# How to show the grid in python with squared cells?

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, grid, cell

I want to plot a circle on a grid in python. I just need python to show the grid with squared cells. I wrote the following code, but it shows the grid with NON-squared cells.

Can anyone tell me how to make the grid cells be squared ?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

p=8

R=0.484*p

t=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)

x=R*np.cos(t)
y=R*np.sin(t)

plt.axis("equal")

plt.grid(True, which='both', axis='both')

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: BTW for code block you just need to write \``` at the beginning and then \``` at the end completely. You don't need to do it every line

Comment: Note that the issue is `plt.axis("equal")`. Check my answer and the linked docs for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `plt.axis("equal")` and instead set [`plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html), which precisely sets the ratio of y-unit to x-unit of the axis scaling:

```
plt.grid(True, which='both', axis='both')
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

Which would be the same as setting `plt.axis('square')`.

Note that as mentioned in the docs, `plt.axis("equal")` is equal to setting `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')`, which will not produce the expected output, since  data limits may not be respected in this case.

The above will give:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is correct. I am new in python. Could you please tell me how to put the coordinate origin at the center of the circle?
@yatu

Comment: It is right? (0,0) is in the center @MohammedAlhissi In any case, for a new question, I kindly encourage you to ask a new question here in SO. Otherwise the answers might mislead future readers

Answer (score 1):

If you add this line after `plt.grid()` it will write all the x-ticks and the squares will be squared:

```
plt.xticks(range(-6, 6))
```

[image]